# Grails - null id error when accessing ServiceClass method in Domain beforeInsert

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm doing some encryption in my domain classes beforeInsert and it works just fine. When I move the code to a service class though I get this error

```
| Error 2014-09-01 10:33:50,229 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.domain.MyDomainClass entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
| Error 2014-09-01 10:33:50,239 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: null id in com.domain.MyDomainClass entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
Message: null id in com.domain.MyDomainClass entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    Line | Method
->>   35 | beforeInsert                     in com.domain.MyDomainClass
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    153 | call                             in org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.EventTriggerCaller$MethodCaller
|     96 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.EventTriggerCaller
|     47 | onApplicationEvent               in org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener
|      7 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

**MyDomainClass.groovy**

```
class MyDomainClass {
    …
    String password

    static constraints = {
        …
    }

    def securityService
    static transients = ['securityService']

    def beforeInsert() {    
        password = securityService.encryptData(password)
    }
}
```

**SecurityService.groovy**

```
class SecurityService {
    def encryptData(plainText) {
        …
        return encryptedData
    }
}
```

Any ideas what this is and how to work around it?  If it matters the data is coming in via `BootStrap.groovy` since I'm still testing.

Comment: have you defined your `securityService` in `transients`?

Comment: @injecteer - I have not, I was under the impression that since I'm using 'def' I don't need to add it to the transients list.

Comment: no, you are wrong on this one :) only `static` and `final` fields by default are excluded from persisting. so, you have to define the injected services in `transients`

Comment: Thanks again @injecteer - I tried doing, based on the docs, `static transients = ['securityService']`, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: why is your service defined as `@Transactional`?

Comment: @injecteer - that code got baked in by grails when I created the class

Comment: then remove it. seems like it creates a parasite transaction

Comment: @injecteer - removed, but unfortunately that didn't cause any change in the result.  Thanks for the help though :D

Comment: I have pretty much the same code in my domain classes, it's working like charm. post the rest of your stacktrace

Comment: @injecteer - I updated the original post with the full stacktrace